# flutter route settings name is null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a simple navigation logger in my flutter app. Created
a new class extending RouteObserver:

```
class AuthMiddleware extends RouteObserver {
  AuthMiddleware();

  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    print(
        "PUSH FROM ${previousRoute.settings.name} TO ${route.settings.name} ");
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    print(
        "POP FROM ${previousRoute.settings.name} TO ${route.settings.name}");
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
  }
}
```

And then assigned it to MaterialApp:

```
   MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      theme: THEME_DATA,
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        String? routeName = settings.name;
        Widget getPage() {
          switch (routeName) {
            case "/about":
              return AboutPage();
            default:
              return HomePage();
          }
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => getPage());
      },
      navigatorObservers: [AuthMiddleware()], //***Set created observer here***
    ),
```

I was expecting to see that it will print something like

```
PUSH FROM / TO /about
```

But I can only see:

```
PUSH FROM null TO null
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to pass settings as a second parameter to `MaterialPageRoute`

```
return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => getPage(), settings: settings);
```